# How to set a starting position using XDrawPoint

Tags: c, position, x11

I am using `XDrawPoint(d, w, DefaultGC(d, s), x, y) ;` from X11 library in C to draw a point on the screen. The `x` and `y` are the x and y coordinates in which the point will be drawn.

The problem is that if I want to plot `XDrawPoint(d, w, DefaultGC(d, s), -x, y) ;` the point does not show up on the screen. I think it is because the initial position is set to 0,0 which make the point disappear.

Is it possible to set the starting position in the middle of the screen, so when plotting negative x and y coordinates, the points still show up?

thanks

Comment: Calculate your points in whatever coordinate system you want, then transform the coordinates just before sending them to `XDraw...` functions.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no way to change the origin from the upper left corner when calling `XDrawPoint()`.

Although `XDrawPoints()` allows you to specify a mode of `CoordModePrevious` to specify coordinates relative to the previous, I'm assuming you don't want to draw a point at the center of the window prior to each point.

One possible way to achieve a central origin for plotting would be to calculate it yourself and add your points as offsets

using a simple struct:

```
typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
} ORIGIN;

ORIGIN origin;
```

and then setting it to the middle of the window `w`:

```
Window       urw;              // unused root window
unsigned int ux, uy, ub, ud;   // unused width, height, border, depth
unsigned int w, h;

XGetGeometry(d, w, &urw, &ux, &uy, &w, &h, &ub, &ud);

origin.x = w/2;
origin.y = h/2;
```

and finally using that as an offset for your plotting:

```
XDrawPoint(d, w, DefaultGC(d, s), origin.x+x, origin.y+y);
```

Of course you would have to recalculate your origin if the window were to be resized and odd sizes will truncate when divided by 2.

Comment: if I have a screen size 300 by 300, then your solution adds 150 to x and 150 to y coordinates? the thing is that I am trying to draw a line in each octants and interchanging x1,x2,y1,y2 for the line does not mirror the line, it draws it somewhere else.

Comment: I supposed I misread the question. I was under the impression you wanted the coordinate range to change from 0 to 300 to -150 to +150.